# Which is the best way to get posts in wordpress wp_query or query_posts()?

Tags: wordpress

I have been working in wordpress and even I am not sure why am I using **wp_query** sometimes and **query_posts** some times. Is there any circumstances where we are supposed to use **wp_query** over **query_posts** or vice versa?

Comment: the perfect answer is found here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/82677